# serverside datatable checkbox doesnot wroked well for all pages

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, checkbox, datatables

I have a server side datatable with a checkbox as last column.

In this when I check a checkbox and goes to another page or I search some value and returns the checking disappears.

How do I make this checkbox remain checked?

I am using php and my view part is

```
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered bootstrap-datatable datatable" path="result/mark-list-json/<?php echo $selected_exam; ?>/" id="servertable123"><!--table starts-->

                     <thead>
                         <tr>
                              <th width="5%">Sl</th>
                              <th width="7%">Reg No</th>
                              <th width="7%">Name</th>
                              <th width="10%">School</th>
                              <th width="10%">Mark</th>
                              <th width="5%">Rank</th>
                              <th width="5%">Publish</th>


                         </tr>
                     </thead>

                 </table>
```

and model function

```
  function mark_list_json($exam_name = '') {

        $exam_code = '';
        if($exam_name!=''){
        $examcde= $this->db->fetch_object($this->db->query("SELECT exam_code FROM exam WHERE exam_id=$exam_name"));

        foreach($examcde as $examcde){
            $exam_code = $examcde->exam_code;

        }}

        $exam_name=$this->db->escape($exam_name);

        $aColumns = array("sl", "student_rollno", "student_name" ,"student_school","mark_mark","student_rank","student_publish");

        $aQuery = "student_id as sl,student_rollno, student_name,  student_school,mark_mark,(CASE mark_remarks WHEN '0' THEN  ( FIND_IN_SET( mark_mark, (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( mark_mark ORDER BY mark_mark DESC )FROM mark JOIN student ON student_id=mark_student WHERE student_status=1 AND student_exam= $exam_name ))  ) WHEN 'Absent' THEN 'Absent' WHEN 'Result Pending' THEN 'Result Pending' ELSE '' END) as student_rank,student_publish";

        $sIndexColumn = "student_id";

        $sTable = "student  JOIN class ON student_class=class_id JOIN mark ON mark_student=student_id";

        $sLimit = "";

        $iDisplayStart = isset($_GET['iDisplayStart']) ? $_GET['iDisplayStart'] : 0;

        $iDisplayLength = isset($_GET['iDisplayLength']) ? $_GET['iDisplayLength'] : 0;

        if (isset($_GET['iDisplayStart']) && $iDisplayLength != '-1') {
            $sLimit = " LIMIT " . $this->db->escape($iDisplayStart) . ", " . $this->db->escape($iDisplayLength);
        }


      $sOrder = " ";


          if (isset($_GET['iSortCol_0']) && $_GET['iSortCol_0'] == 0 && $_GET['iSortingCols'] == 1)
            $sOrder = " ORDER BY  mark_mark DESC";
          else if (isset($_GET['iSortCol_0'])) {
            $sOrder = "ORDER BY  ";
            for ($i = 0; $i < intval($_GET['iSortingCols']); $i++)
                if ($_GET['bSortable_' . intval($_GET['iSortCol_' . $i])] == "true")
                    $sOrder .= $aColumns[intval($_GET['iSortCol_' . $i])] . ($_GET['sSortDir_' . $i] === 'asc' ? ' asc' : ' desc') . ", ";

            $sOrder = substr_replace($sOrder, "", -2);
            if ($sOrder == "ORDER BY")
                $sOrder = "";
        }

        $sSearch = isset($_GET['sSearch']) ? $_GET['sSearch'] : "";
        if($exam_name!=''){
              $sWhere = "WHERE student_status=1 AND student_exam=$exam_name ";
        }else{
             $sWhere = "WHERE student_status=1 AND student_exam=0 "; 
        }

        if ($sSearch != "") {
            $sWhere = "WHERE (";
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($aColumns); $i++) {

                if ($i == 1 || $i == 2) {
                    $sWhere .= $aColumns[$i] . " LIKE '%" . $_GET['sSearch'] . "%' OR ";
                }
            }
            $sWhere = substr_replace($sWhere, "", -3);
            $sWhere .= ')';
        }


        $sQuery = " SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS $aQuery FROM $sTable $sWhere   $sOrder  $sLimit ";
        $rResult = $this->db->query($sQuery);


        $iResult = $this->db->query('select FOUND_ROWS() AS found_rows');
        $iFilteredTotal = $this->db->row($iResult)->found_rows;


        $sQuery = " SELECT $sIndexColumn FROM   $sTable ";
        $aResultTotal = $this->db->query($sQuery);

        $iTotal = $this->db->num_rows($aResultTotal);


        $sEcho = isset($_GET['sEcho']) ? $_GET['sEcho'] : "";
        $output = array(
             "dt_params" => "doprint_html('result/print_mark_list/".$exam_name."/?".$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']."')",
            "sEcho" => intval($sEcho),
            "iTotalRecords" => $iTotal,
            "iTotalDisplayRecords" => $iFilteredTotal,
            "aaData" => array()
        );


        $sl_count = $iDisplayStart + 1;
        foreach ($this->db->fetch_object($rResult) as $aRow) {


            $row = array();

            for ($i = 0; $i < count($aColumns); $i++) {

                if ($aColumns[$i] == 'sl') {

                    $row[] = $sl_count;
                }
                else if ($aColumns[$i] == 'student_rollno') {

                    $row[] = $exam_code.$aRow->$aColumns[$i];

                }
                else if ($aColumns[$i] == 'student_publish') {

                    if($aRow->$aColumns[$i]==1){
                      $checked='checked'  ;
                      $sl=1;
                    }else{
                      $checked=''  ;  
                      $sl='';
                    }
                      $row[] ='<input type="checkbox" name="checkAll[]" value="'.$sl.'"  id="checkAll"'.$checked.'>
                          <input type="hidden" name="std_ids[]" value="'.$aRow->sl.'"  id="std_ids">';

                }else {

                    $row[] = $aRow->$aColumns[$i];
                }
            }

            $output['aaData'][] = $row;
            $sl_count++;
        }

        return json_encode($output);
    }
```

and the script is

```
    datatable_server12('#servertable123');

     function datatable_server12(id,column){

        var base_url  = $("meta[name=baseurl]").attr("content");


        var tStatus = false;

        if($("#tools").length) { 
            var tools = $("#tools").html();  
            tStatus = true; 
        }

        if ($(id).length) { 


            var rowCount = ($(id + ' tr th').length);

            var mColumns  = [];

            var new_rowCount =  rowCount;

            if(tStatus) { 

               new_rowCount = rowCount - 1;

            }

            for(var i = 0; i < new_rowCount; i++){

                mColumns.push(i) ;
            }

            $.fn.dataTableExt.sErrMode = 'throw';




            var oTable = $(id).dataTable({                

//              "sDom": "<'row-fluid'<'span9'<'input-tools'>><'span3'<'export-btn'T>>><'row-fluid'<'span12't>>",
               "sDom": "<'row-fluid'<'span3 pull-left'l><'span3 pull-right'f>>t<'export-btn'T<'span6 pull-right'p>><'row-fluid' <'span12 pull-right'i>>",
                "bProcessing": false,
                "bServerSide": true,   
                "sServerMethod": "GET",
                "sAjaxSource":  base_url + $(id).attr("path"),                 
                "oTableTools": {
                    "sSwfPath": "assets/lib/datatables/media/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
                    "aButtons": [
                    {
                        "sExtends": "text",
                        "sButtonText": "Export to Excel",
//                        'mColumns':mColumns
 fnComplete:function(e){

                                 var valid = true; 
                                  var name=$('#exam').val(); 
                                    var class2= $('#class2').val();

                                if(valid){
                                    window.location = 'marklist/export_marklist/'+ name+ '/'+ class2+'/'; 
                                }
                           }       

                    },
                    {
                                "sExtends": "csv",
                                "sButtonText": "Export CSV"
                            },
                    {
                        "sExtends": "pdf",
                        "sButtonText": "Export to PDF",
                        'mColumns':mColumns
                    }
                    ]
                },
                "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
                "aLengthMenu": [[10, 50, 100, 1000,5000,10000], [10, 50, 100, 1000,5000,10000]],
                "iDisplayLength" : 5000,
                "bFilter": true,
                "aaSorting": [[ 0, "desc" ]],

                "oLanguage": {
                    "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_",
                    "sSearch": ""
                },
                "fnPreDrawCallback": function() {
                    $(".loading").fadeIn();  
                },
                "fnDrawCallback": function() {
                    $(".loading").fadeOut(); 
                    $('.po').popover({ html : true  });
                },                               
                "fnCreatedRow": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex ) { 

                    if(tStatus){
                        $('td:last-child', nRow).html(tools.replace(/{id}/g,$('td:last-child', nRow).html()));
                    }


                },

                "fnInitComplete": function() {       
                    $('.dataTables_filter input').attr("placeholder", "Search"); 
                    if(tStatus){
                        $('.po').popover({
                            html : true
                        });
                    }



                    var timeout = undefined;
                    // Anyone knows how to access table as JQuery object inside fnInitComplete?
                    // $('div.dataTables_filter input:text') works but it's not perfect solution in case
                    // you use multiple tables.
                    $('div.dataTables_filter input:text').unbind('keyup').bind('keyup', function() {

                        if (timeout != undefined) {
                            clearTimeout(timeout);
                        }

                        var $this = this;
                        timeout = setTimeout(function() {
                            timeout = undefined;
                            oTable.fnFilter($($this).val());
                        }, 500);

                    });      

                },

                   "fnServerData": function ( sSource, aoData, fnCallback ) {
                    /* Add some extra data to the sender */
                    //aoData.push( { "name": "more_data", "value": "my_value" } );
                    $.getJSON( sSource, aoData, function (json) { 
                        if(json.filtered_sum){
                          $('#filtered_sum').html(json.filtered_sum);
                        }
                        if(json.dt_params){
                              $("#btn-doprint").attr("onclick", json.dt_params);
                        }
                        if(json.filtered_total){
                            $.each(json.filtered_total, function(index, value) { 
                               $('#'+index).html(value);
                            }); 
                        }
                        fnCallback(json)
                    } );
                },

                //tablesum
                 "fnFooterCallback": function ( nRow, aaData, iStart, iEnd, aiDisplay ) {

                    var tablesum =  String($(id).attr('tablesum'));

                    if (typeof tablesum !== 'undefined' && tablesum !== false) {
                            var  arrTs =  tablesum.split(",");

                            $(arrTs).each(function(index,value) {
                                var arrTsF =  arrTs[index].split(":");  

                                var total = 0;
                                for ( var i=0 ; i<aaData.length ; i++ )
                                {

                                    var list_item = parseFloat(aaData[i][parseInt(arrTsF[1])]);

                                    if(isNaN(list_item)){
                                        list_item = 0;
                                    }  

                                    total = total + list_item;
                                }  

                                $("#" + arrTsF[0]).html(Math.round(total));                        
                            });
                    }

                    var tablecnt =  String($(id).attr('tablecnt'));

                    if (typeof tablecnt !== 'undefined' && tablecnt !== false) {
                            var  arrTs =  tablecnt.split(",");

                            $(arrTs).each(function(index,value) {
                                var arrTsF =  arrTs[index].split(":");  

                                var totaltablecnt = 0;
                                for ( var i=0 ; i<aaData.length ; i++ )
                                {
                                    var list_item = parseFloat(aaData[i][parseInt(arrTsF[1])]);
                                    totaltablecnt++;
                                }  

                                $("#" + arrTsF[0]).html(totaltablecnt);                        
                            });
                    }
                } 

            });
            if (typeof(column) != "undefined" && column!=false ) {  fnShowHide(column,oTable); }

            dt_server_api = oTable;
        }

            }
```

how to solve this?